# Round edge for circular progressbar Android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-progressbar

I'm trying to achieve this view,

[image]

What i have right now:

[image]

I need the progressbar to have rounded corner as the one above. Adding radius in Xml doesn't seem to work.

*circular_pb.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="6"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
            android:useLevel="true">
            <corners android:radius="100dp"/>
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#999999"
                android:endColor="#999999"
                android:startColor="#999999"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="270">
            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="6"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
                android:useLevel="true">
                <corners android:radius="100dp"/>
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="0"
                    android:pivotX="50%"
                    android:pivotY="50%"
                    android:toDegrees="360" />
                <gradient
                    android:centerColor="#00FF00"
                    android:endColor="#00FF00"
                    android:startColor="#00FF00"
                    android:type="sweep" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```